# How to iterate a list and erase from it?

Tags: c++, c++11, iteration, containers

I'm having a lot of trouble with List iterators, and I asked a question previously but was not able to get the solution I was looking for.

I have a circular list, and I must replace the value of node n with node n + (step). I must then erase node n + (step). When I erase it puts the iterator to the element after the erased element. I need the iterator back at node n. How the heck can I do this because everytime I erase n + (step) I get an invalid iterator. My input is 5 and 2.

Please let me know if there is a better datastructure to do this with, if there is no way to iterate and erase from a list. I thought of using a Vector, but I would have to shift elements down and that would be costly if there are a lot of elements.

```
#include "roulette.h"
#include <iostream>

uint roulette(uint people, uint step)
{
    std::list<uint>::iterator iterator;
    for(uint i = people; i > 0; i--)
        gl_myList.push_front(i);

    iterator = gl_myList.begin();
    while(people > 1)
    {
        iterator = advanceList(iterator, step - 1);
        uint replaceValue = *iterator; // Node n's value

        auto tempIterator = advanceList(iterator, step);
        uint newValue = *tempIterator; //Node n + step value

        iterator = gl_myList.erase(tempIterator);
        //Makes it past the erase function ONCE.

        //Puts the iterator back to the correct spot, and sets it value
        while(*iterator != replaceValue)
        {
            advanceList(iterator, 1);

        }
        *iterator = newValue;

        people--;
    }

    return *iterator;
}
```

advanceList

```
#include "roulette.h"
std::list<uint>::iterator advanceList(std::list<uint>::iterator& start, uint step)
{
    for(uint i = 0; i < step; i++)
    {
        start++;
        if(start == gl_myList.end())
        {
            start = gl_myList.begin();
        }
    }

    return start;
}
```

Comment: Question looks like homework with misunderstood problem statement.
Erasing from vector of easily movable objects (uint) in not slow. Anyway it is not about removing from list. Your code is full of bugs without it.
In each iteration of your loop you advance "step" positions twice. Code that puts back to correct spot assumes element values are unique.
What should be your "n" after you perform the operation?

Comment: I ended up using a Vector. Thanks for letting me know it wasn't slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the result of your `erase()` call correctly, nor are you checking for `.end()` prior to the next iteration. I'm all-but-certain the following is what you're at least attempting to do. And note, this is still brittle, as it is anything-but-ready for edge cases (like an initial empty list, a 0-step-value, etc.):

```
std::list<uint>::iterator advanceList(std::list<uint>::iterator& start, uint step)
{
    for(uint i = 0; i < step; i++)
    {
        if(++start == gl_myList.end())
            start = gl_myList.begin();
    }

    return start;
}

uint roulette(uint people, uint step)
{
    std::list<uint>::iterator it;
    for(uint i = people; i > 0; i--)
        gl_myList.push_front(i);

    it = gl_myList.begin();
    while (gl_myList.size() > 1)
    {
        it = gl_myList.erase(advanceList(it, step - 1));
        if (it == gl_myList.end())
            it = gl_myList.begin();
    }

    return *it;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's fix a very simple bug in your code. advanceList modifies it's argument, when you call

```
auto tempIterator = advanceList(iterator, step);
```

both `iterator` and `tempIterator` are changed. Is it what you want to achieve?

Also in your `advanceList` if start was at the end as you entered teh function you must replace it with `begin` before entering loop.

Comment: Actually, if start == end before the loop then the container is empty and there is nothing to do.  In that case, simply return or ASSERT if the expectation is for the caller to only pass an iterator if there is something in the container.  Also, there could be a check to see if there is at least two elements.  I don't think that there is anything for the function to do if there is one element.

Answer (score 0):

You're not approaching this problem in the right way, I believe.

The best way to do what you want, is first to separate whathever has to be deleted from what has to be kept. You can do that with **std::partition** or **std::stable_partition** in header **algorithm**. Then you can delete a range of elements from your container easy and clean.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// ...
bool differentFrom3(int n) { return n != 3; }

vector<int> v = { 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 7, 3, 1 };

// move all the 3's to one end of the vector
vector<int>::iterator it = stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), differentFrom3);

// v is now arranged in the following order:
// { 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3 }
//                        ^
//                        +--- it
//
// and it points to the first element whose value is 3 (in this case, v[7])
// Now you can delete everything from the it to the end of the vector.
v.erase(it, v.end());
```

I'm using **stable_partition** here because it keeps the relative position between elements. If you don't care about that you can use **partition** instead.